# Push new item into array to mongo document

Tags: mongodb

I have a field called permissions, it's an array of permissions, regarding to specific section of my app, and each section has inside update, create, delete and update with a boolean value.

I want to push a new "section" with default values, but some is going wrong. This is the query

```
db.getCollection('users').updateOne({ nick_name: 'a.siurob' }, 
{ 
    $push: { 
        'permissions': {
            'account_control': {
                'update': true,
                'read': true,
                'create': true,
                'delete': true
            }
        } 
    } 
});
```

And it returns

```
The field 'permissions' must be an array but is of type object in document {_id: ObjectId('618d6aeb93b594490ea6c2eb')}
```

This is the current structure of the permissions value

```
permissions: {
    "dashboard": {
        "read": false,
        "create": false,
        "update": false,
        "delete": false
    },
    "meals": {
        "read": true,
        "create": true,
        "update": true,
        "delete": true
    },
    "ingredients": {
        "read": true,
        "create": true,
        "update": true,
        "delete": true
    },
    "users": {
        "read": true,
        "create": true,
        "update": true,
        "delete": true
    },
}
```

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query

- push is for arrays but you have nested document
- i think you just need `$set` with path(. syntax) to add the field inside the nested document

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=6312a37678a49d8782851499)

```js
db.users.updateOne(
{"nick_name": {"$eq": "a.siurob"}},
{"$set": 
 {"permissions.account_control": 
   {"update": true, "read": true, "create": true, "delete": true}}})
```